# receive another android phones gps location through SMS

Tags: android, google-maps, gps, sms, tracking

i am trying to create an app that in theory will track an animal who has a gps chipped collar and display it on a map.
i currently have the map running showing the users current position however need to also display the "animal"(test phone).
i plan on using another phone as an example for the report however am unsure how to receive the other phones gps coordinates.
i was advised to uses sms messages instead of the internet servers as this may be too complicated for my timescale.
what i want to know, is if it is possible to get my app to send a SMS to another phone and request its GPS location and receive it via a SMS and display on a Google map?
if it is do you know of a tutorial to do so.
Any information would be greatly appreciated.
Thank You in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not very simple and fast to implement it. First you need a component(Could be a broadcastReceiver) on the test phone "waiting" for the sms. You could register your receiver in order to trigger the sms event and check for the sender for example, or the text itself to see if it's a "request-gps" sms. When you receive the sms you could start a Service to track your gps location, and when you get it, you could reply to this number with the location. In your application (which send firstly the sms) you receive the sms with the gps location and you could display the position in a map.

So the user send the sms:

```
smsManager.sendTextMessage(smsNumber, null, requestGps, null, null);
```

On the "animal side" there is the receiver:

```
   @Override
      public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {


        //---get the SMS message passed in---
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();        
        SmsMessage[] msgs = null;
        String sender = "";            
        if (bundle != null)
        {
            //---retrieve the SMS message received---
            Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
            msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];            
            for (int i=0; i<msgs.length; i++){
                msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);                
                sender += msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress(); 
            }   
        } 
  }
```

On the service (Always "animal" side) you register for GPS location and then you reply to the SMS

```
smsManager.sendTextMessage(smsNumber, null, gpsLocation, null, null);
```

And in user side you receive the sms exactly as the "animal" does, and then you display the gps coordinates on your map

Comment: ok so the animal side(2nd phone) must have another app that will wait for a command(text) then auto reply with the gps coordinates then my app must read the sms for the coordinates and then display on app. would that be the idea yea?

Comment: Yeah you're right. That's the first idea that came in my mind. But I think there could be many ideas regarding this, such as using back-end services.

Comment: Sorry, my fault. Back-end services are third parties services on the internet that give you features like push notifications. I give you an example: when the animal receive the sms, it sends the gps location to this services (Almost all of them provide you an SDK to integrate in your app). And on the user side you receive data through a notification. It's exact the same process as SMSs. The only difference is that you use internet connection. I've had a look at Netmera back end services recently for example. So it's a matter of your choice.

Comment: ahh ok. im not sure i will be able to use that unfortunetly.

Comment: clicked enter there by accident aha. so basicly depending on my choice i will have to have a seperate application on the test phone to receive the message and reply the co-ords, either made by myself or by finding another app which does the same operation?

Comment: That's right. I don't know if there is already an app that automaticly replies to an sms with GPS coordinates. It could be, there is a plenty of apps out there :D Anyway, you got it.

Comment: hello again im sorry about this but i just wanted to check befiore startking the actual code..the code you left above, smsManager.sendTextMessage(smsNumber, null, requestGps, null, null);     this is the code to make my app send a text(smsNumber=phone number to send to?)(gpslocation null null = long and alt?)

Comment: then the main body is the code i should put into a seperate app on the "animal phone" which handles the receiveing of the text? i then have to add my own code to calculate the gps and attach it to the sms? which is sent using the 3rd code you stated?

Comment: i left this out as i read it will let you know i rpelied again.

Comment: Yes you're right. the 2 null values are not the coordinates. You send the coordinates into the sms text that is a string. I don't remember the which parameters take the sendMessageText but you only need the receiver phone number and the message text which in this case is gpsLocation. It's your matter then to parse the string and get the 2 coordinates. By the way, I think you've understood how it works. You register a receiver for getting sms on the animal, when you get the sms you start getting location and once you got it, you reply to the sender your current location through the sms text

Comment: thanks for replying again, im sorry for keeping at you aha, stressing out over a deadline...yea i think i understand what you mean and what needs to be done :) i believe i will need to somehow set up the app to auto send the sms every ? minutes so that a trail is created and the location is kept up-to-date however im still unsure what the main block of the code you left actualy does...im okay at understanding what should be done but when it comes to actually coding im not great at starting it aha

Comment: and this is the last time i will bother you :)

Comment: If you want to automatically update your location you just need to make the animal phone sending automatically the gps position to your number every x minutes. The main part is the code of a BroadcastReceiver. When you create a BroadcastReceiver in Android you declare it in the manifest file with a given action: android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED. When it's done it, the onReceive method will be called when a new sms is retrieved. After that you could do whathever you want to get your position and replying to the sms :) don't worry, I'm glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

This is quite possible. What you need is receiver with RECEIVE_SMS filter on both phones. The first app can send SMS with some specific code to the phone on tracking side. In the onReceive method, you can check if the SMS contains your code and if it matches, you can start tracking location by creating a LocationManager object and registering a listener using [requestLocationUpdates](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#requestLocationUpdates%28long,%20float,%20android.location.Criteria,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29) method. In the [onLocationChanged](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationListener.html#onLocationChanged%28android.location.Location%29) method, you can send an SMS back to the first mobile the latitude and longitude details.

The receiver in the first mobile can parse this latitude and longitude values and show it in your application.